# Trying to add a related to list between Leads and Quotes in vTiger

Tags: php, mysql, crm, vtiger

I am trying to add a related to list between the Lead and Quote module in vTiger.

Ultimately, I would like the user to be able to select a quote to be attached to a lead (and possibly vice versa).

As far as I can tell, I have to add the field to the Lead.php file in the Lead module, however I'm doing what I can tell as far as documentation (which is incredibly sparse) and I'm seeing no new fields in the Lead module.

Here's my code:

```
var $additional_column_fields = Array('smcreatorid', 'smownerid', 'contactid','potentialid' ,'crmid', 'quoteid');

// This is the list of vtiger_fields that are in the lists.
var $list_fields = Array(
    'Last Name'=>Array('leaddetails'=>'lastname'),
    'First Name'=>Array('leaddetails'=>'firstname'),
    'Company'=>Array('leaddetails'=>'company'),
    'Phone'=>Array('leadaddress'=>'phone'),
    'Website'=>Array('leadsubdetails'=>'website'),
    'Email'=>Array('leaddetails'=>'email'),
    'Assigned To'=>Array('crmentity'=>'smownerid'),
    'Quote'=>Array('quotes'=>'subject')
);

var $list_fields_name = Array(
    'Last Name'=>'lastname',
    'First Name'=>'firstname',
    'Company'=>'company',
    'Phone'=>'phone',
    'Website'=>'website',
    'Email'=>'email',
    'Assigned To'=>'assigned_user_id',
     'Subject'=>'subject',
);
```

Notice, I've added quote specific information.

Ideally I just want to have a link between the two of them - much like you would link an opportunity and a contact or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

Your related to field not pointing to the table quotes. OR your related to field is not working properly. So check out your code for which you have set related to field. i already post an answer to your other questions.

[URL Code Generating "undefined" for vTiger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941882/url-code-generating-undefined-for-vtiger)

[Not an object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940512/not-an-object-error/19946659#19946659)