# URL Code Generating "undefined" for vTiger

Tags: php, vtiger

For some reason, my code is generating module=undefined:

```
/index.php?module=undefined&action=Popup&html=Popup_picker&form=vtlibPopupView&forfield=Quotes&srcmodule=Leads&forrecord=1695
```

The problem is that I define the module directly in my script:

```
$field0->setRelatedModules(Array('Quotes'));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my complete code:

```
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
//(module name without space)
$module = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Leads');
$module->initWebservice();

// Create Block instance
$block1 = new Vtiger_Block();
$block1 = Vtiger_Block::getInstance('LBL_LEAD_INFORMATION', $module);

$field0 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field0->name = 'quotes';
$field0->column = 'quotes';
$field0->label = 'Test2';
$field0->uitype = 10;
$field0->typeofdata = 'V~O';
//$field0->setRelatedModules(Array('Quotes'));
$field0->setRelatedModules(Array('quotes'));
$block1->addField($field0);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to set related module after adding the field. You can't set relation to any module before adding field.

Add the code below to the addField line.

```
$block1->addField($field0);
$field0->setRelatedModules(Array('Quotes'));
```

And also i think you have to add field to table the lead table.

So update your code like this.

```
$field0 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field0->name = 'quotes';
$field0->column = 'quotes';
$field0->table = $module->basetable; 
$field0->label = 'Test2';
$field0->uitype = 10;
$field0->typeofdata = 'V~O';
$block1->addField($field0);
$field0->setRelatedModules(Array('Quotes'));
```

Comment: This generates a popup, but when I try to select a value from this popup, the field does not populate.

Comment: Also, it still says, "module=undefined"

Comment: Ok then get your field id number from vtiger_field table and go to table vtiger_fieldmodulerel and check whether any entry is there for that filed or not? if yes then you might have problem in coding.

Comment: Where would the problem in coding be? I've added it to vtiger_fieldmodulerel

Comment: Have you tried for new field instead of already existing. Just add new field using code above and check after that. i can't say where you are having problem. Bcoz it comes from many files such as Utils files.

Comment: It adds the fields, but I'm still getting "undefined" and "module not found". It does create a relationship in vtiger_fieldmodulerel between leads and quotes though.